# get request in js not appending form data in the url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

It's an express router module for a form page that takes in data for adding the details of a book. But upon submit, the url does not contain any of the form data in it. It is just blank beyond the '?'
The url shows 'http://localhost:5000/admin/addBook/add?'

```
<form class="container col-md-5 signupform bg-white my-4 py-3 formShadow" method="GET"
                action="/admin/addBook/add" , onsubmit="return validate()">
                <label class="form-label ">ENTER BOOK TITLE:</label>
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Book Title" id="title">
                <br>
                <label class="form-label">ENTER BOOK AUTHOR:</label>
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Book Author" id="author">
                <br>
                <label class="form-label">ENTER BOOK GENRE:</label>
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Book Author" id="genre">
                <br>
                <label class="form-label ">UPLOAD IMAGE:</label>
                <input class="form-control " type="file" id="image">
                <br>
                <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn loginbutton" id="add">ADD</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your form elements have a `name` attribute, which is what the browser uses as the key in the key/value pairs.  Since there are no keys, there's no data to send.

Add `name` attributes:

```
<input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Book Title" id="title" name="title">
<!-- etc. -->
```